# toggle div with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a set of checkboxes. When I check the checkbox with the value 4, I want the checkbox with the value 2 to automatically get checked and also show a div with a message in it. When the checkbox with the value 4 is unchecked, I want the message to disappear. Message toggles with checkbox value 4.

I have been able to get the message to disappear after unchecking the checkbox value 4, but when I check it again, the message doesn't appear again and the checkbox with the value 2 doesn't auto checked again either.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="user_role_ids_"><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" id="user_role_ids_"><br>
```

JS:

```
var chk1 = $("input#user_role_ids_[type='checkbox'][value='4']");
var chk2 = $("input#user_role_ids_[type='checkbox'][value='2']");
var checkmsg = $('<div/>', {'class': 'checkbox-message'}).html('If you are a Copywriter   
    Manager, you are also a Copywriter')

chk1.on('change', function(){
    $(checkmsg).insertAfter("input#user_role_ids_[type='checkbox'][value='4']");
    chk2.prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

I am aware that you are not suppose to have two elements with the same id. Please do not comment on that.

http://jsfiddle.net/q5Rr8/4/

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Just put the message in the HTML directly and toggle its state.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) the message like this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q5Rr8/5/)**.

- First Hide the element:

  ```
  var checkmsg = $('<div/>', .... Copywriter').hide();
  ```
- Then toggle with the `on(change)`

  ```
  chk1.on('change', function(){
    $(checkmsg).insertAfter("input#... [value='4']").toggle();
    chk2.prop('checked',this.checked);
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

With a CSS solution and adding the "dynamic" HTML directly into the layout, there is no need to have JavaScript involved

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" /><span>My Message!</span><br>
```

**CSS:**

```
[type="checkbox"] + span {
    display:none;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
    display: inline;
}
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/MxUU6/

---

If you want to do it in JavaScript with the same HTML it is just

```
$("#formId").on("change", '[type="checkbox"]', function() {
   $(this).next("span").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Add classes to make it more specific if you have additional checkboxes on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you target the checkboxes by simply their id and make sure they are unique

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/q5Rr8/7/

`var chk1 = $("#user_role_ids1");

    var chk2 = $("#user_role_ids2");

    chk1.on('change', function(){

    $(checkmsg).insertAfter("#user_role_ids1");

        chk2.prop('checked',this.checked);

    });`

Be careful of using css only solution as ':checked' is not supported in internet explorer before version 9, use feature detection or simply let javascript take care of it all

http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/